# jQuery validate not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need this validation to fire when the div button is clicked.  If the validation is successful, I want it to alert "is good".

Unfortunately, although validation fires and all rules are checked, it does not error if a required field is blank.  It will error for any of the other checks tho.

Finally, if I fill in the fields correctly and click the button, nothing happens.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Submit prompted password reset
$("#passwordResetButton").click(function() {

    $("#passwordResetForm").validate({  
        rules: {
            password: { required: true, minlength: 8, maxlength: 40, remote: { url: "/ajax/isPasswordOK", data: { product: function() { return $("#password").val();  } } } },
            confirmPassword: { required: true, equalTo: "#password" },
        }, 
        messages: { 
            password: { required: "Please enter a password", minlength: "Password must be at least 8 characters long", remote: "Password should contain: <li>At least one upper case character <li>At least one lower case character <li>At least one number <li>And may not contain any of the following: \\;-\")(&*='|$" },
            confirmPassword: { required: "Please confirm your password", equalTo: "The passwords do not match" },
          }, 
        onkeyup: false, //turn off auto validate whilst typing
        onblur: true,
        afterValidation: function() {
            alert('is good');
        }
    });
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="passwordResetForm" style="width: 480px; margin: auto;">
        <div class="row"><p class="lead">Let's reset that password</p></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-8 large-4 columns"><label>New Password:</label></div>
            <div class="small-12 large-6 columns"><input name="password" id="password" type="password" size="20"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-8 large-4 columns"><label>Confirm Password:</label></div>
            <div class="small-12 large-6 columns"><input name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" type="password" size="20"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-offset-10 small-3 large-1 columns">
                <div id="passwordResetButton"  class="small button">Submit</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

**1**)  `.validate()` is the ***initialization*** method of the plugin, not a method for testing the form.  In other words, do not put it inside of a `click` handler or it won't be ready when you need it.  Put `.validate()` inside of the DOM ready event handler so it's fired once when the page is created, then the form is immediately ready for validation.

**2**)  There is no such option as `onblur` for this plugin. It is called `onfocusout` and the option is already activated by default.  [Setting this type of option to `true` is not valid](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#onfocusout) and will likely break something, so simply leave it out of the initialization entirely.

**3**)  There is no such option/function called `afterValidation:`.  You cannot just "invent" callback functions... jQuery plugins have to have these things [already specifically built into them](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).  If you want to fire something on a valid form, use the supplied `submitHandler:` callback function.

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    alert('is good');
    return false;
}
```

**4**)  Use a `<input type="submit" />` or a `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` for the form's submit.  This way, the plugin can automatically capture the click event and handle the submit as designed.

**5**)  Minor note:  For your custom messages, simply use `{0}` and the rule's parameter will be inserted automatically.  This kind of code is easier to maintain.

```
minlength: "Password must be at least {0} characters long",
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/J9N3g/**

I suggest that you review the full documentation here:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#passwordResetForm").validate({
        rules: {
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                maxlength: 40,
                remote: {
                    url: "/ajax/isPasswordOK",
                    data: {
                        product: function () {
                            return $("#password").val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            confirmPassword: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#password"
            },
        },
        messages: {
            password: {
                required: "Please enter a password",
                minlength: "Password must be at least {0} characters long",
                remote: "Password should contain: <li>At least one upper case character <li>At least one lower case character <li>At least one number <li>And may not contain any of the following: \\;-\")(&*='|$"
            },
            confirmPassword: {
                required: "Please confirm your password",
                equalTo: "The passwords do not match"
            },
        },
        onkeyup: false, //turn off auto validate whilst typing
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert('is good');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="passwordResetForm" style="width: 480px; margin: auto;">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="lead">Let's reset that password</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-8 large-4 columns">
            <label>New Password:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">
            <input name="password" id="password" type="password" size="20" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-8 large-4 columns">
            <label>Confirm Password:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">
            <input name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" type="password" size="20" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-offset-10 small-3 large-1 columns">
            <input type="submit" id="passwordResetButton" class="small button" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I learned a lot from this post.  It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
afterValidation: function() {
            alert('is good');
        }
```

to

```
submitHandler: function() { alert("is good!") }:
```

See jquery validate option: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

Change div to button, it a best practice

```
<div id="passwordResetButton"  class="small button">Submit</div>
```

to

```
<button id="passwordResetButton"  class="small button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Required error still not displaying, and still nothing happens on a successful validation.  However, if a field was wrong and I change it to be correct, the alert pops up 'is good'.  Not desired behavior.

Comment: That resolved all issues except that alert('is good') still fires whenever a bad field is corrected

Comment: use submitHandler instead of success option

Comment: the password check in remote is fine, it is used elsewhere without difficulty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28182/discussion-between-tamil-selvan-and-lynn-owens)

Comment: Tried nesting the validate in $("#passwordResetForm").submit(function()... if that's what you mean by specifying a submit handler.  That definitely doesn't work, it's like reloading the form everytime I do anything.